# Are there any reasons to avoid using sp_rename for renaming objects?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, sql-server-2014

In the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) it is clearly said:

> Changing any part of an object name can break scripts and stored
>   procedures. We recommend you do not use this statement to rename
>   stored procedures, triggers, user-defined functions, or views;
>   instead, drop the object and re-create it with the new name.

What about renaming:

- primary keys
- unique keys
- foreign keys
- default constraints
- indexes

I am going to rename all of the above objects in order to match our internal naming conventions but I want to write an automatic script for doing this (as there are thousands of constraints).

The only issue I can think off is that if index is used with a `hint` in statement it will be broken.

Could you tell any other reasons not to use the `sp_rename` for such purpose?

Answer (score 6):

- Update

sp_rename upates the name in sys.objects but it does not update the definition or objects referencing it.

- Object definition

> Renaming a stored procedure, function, view, or trigger will not change the name of the corresponding object name in the definition column of the sys.sql_modules catalog view. Therefore, we recommend that sp_rename not be used to rename these object types. Instead, drop and re-create the object with its new name. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx))

When you run this query:

```
Create Procedure Test
as
begin
    set nocount on
end
Go
Exec sp_rename 'Test', 'Tests'
GO
Select * From sys.sql_modules
sp_helptext 'Tests'
```

The `definition` column in `sql_modules` still contains `Test`:

```
object_id   definition ...
599673184   Create Procedure Test as begin set nocount on Select id From T1 end
```

- Rename a Table (or an object)

When an object is rename, any object using it and referencing the old name will fail.

Here are a View and a Table beining renamed:

```
Create Table T1(id int)
Go
Create View V1 AS Select id From dbo.T1
Go  
Exec sp_rename 'T1', 'T2'
```

Again if you look at the definition, both the procedure and the view reference T1 (which does not exist anymore):

```
object_id   definition
759673754   Create Procedure Test as begin set nocount on Select id From T1 end
791673868   Create View V1 AS Select id From dbo.T1
```

And both will fail with this error when you Select from it or Execute it:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.T1'.
Could not use view or function 'V1' because of binding errors.
```

You get the same error if you refresh the view:

```
sp_refreshview 'v1'
```

All objects with references to the old name will break.

- Dependencies

Before renaming an object (table, procedure, function, ...), you can look at its dependencies using `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx)) (deprecated: `sys.sql_dependencies` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174402.aspx), `sys.sysdepends` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190325.aspx))

Comment: I am interested in constraints at all and cases where renaming them could cause a issue.

Comment: Hardcoded indexes in query hint aside, I don't see an issue